# Getting "ArrayOf" prepended to arrays of ActiveRecord objects in XML representation returned by asp.net webservice with Mono

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization, mono

ASP.net web method:

```
[WebMethod()]
public Data.Subtitle[] GetAll()
{
    return Data.Subtitle.FindAll();
}
```

Here's the Subtitle class:

```
[ActiveRecord("Subtitle")]
public class Subtitle : ActiveRecordBase<Subtitle>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Assigned)]
    public int SubId {get;set;}

    [Property()]
    public int SubStreamId {get;set;}

    [Property()]
    public string SubTimeStart {get;set;}

    [Property()]
    public string SubTimeEnd {get;set;}

    [Property()]
    public string SubText {get;set;}

    public Subtitle () { }
}
```

And here's the XML coming back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSubtitle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Subtitle>
    <SubId>862</SubId>
    <SubStreamId>1</SubStreamId>
    <SubTimeStart>00:01:04.4450000</SubTimeStart>
    <SubTimeEnd>00:01:08.2450000</SubTimeEnd>
    <SubText>Wikus van de Merwe
MNU Alien Affairs

</SubText>
  </Subtitle>
  <Subtitle>
    <SubId>863</SubId>
    <SubStreamId>1</SubStreamId>
    <SubTimeStart>00:02:11.3430000</SubTimeStart>
    <SubTimeEnd>00:02:14.8430000</SubTimeEnd>
    <SubText>Sarah Livingstone
Sociologist, Kempton Park University

</SubText>
</Subtitle>
```

I love the simplicity of presenting the data objects as a webservice with one line of code, but I can't seem to get the array of `Subtitle` objects serialized without the "ArrayOf" prefix. My trips through Google have pointed me to WCF facilities that aren't available on Mono, or manual serialization, which I am trying to avoid.

Is there an easy way to present the array of Subtitle objects as `<Subtitles>` in Mono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the record :i use a dirt trick, In my example the xml is serialized then parsed as string, so i am managing a string that contain a xml

```
var arr = myStr.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var arr2 = "";
for (int i = 2; i < arr.Count()-1;i++ )
{
    arr2 += arr[i];
}
```

it cut the lines 0 (xml),1 (arrayofsubtitle) and last (/arrayofsubtitle):

:-3

Comment: Always use `Environment.NewLine` especially in cross-platform apps / apps running cross-platform frameworks (like mono)